# open file with ofstream for edit previous data in C++

Tags: c++, file, ofstream

I have a text file like this:

```
hello every one this is
sample text ...
```

Now I want to edit this file to:

```
olleh every one this is
sample text ...
```

How can I do this by ofstream C++
I use ofstream::app but It's not a way for me!

Comment: Normally you would not do this in-place as it's disaster-prone - write the modified contents to a new file, then rename both.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code generator. Reduce your task into component steps.

Comment: Ok, I use ofstream and read about that in many sources, but I can't find way to do this. so I think Stack Overflow is the best answer :)

Comment: @ Paul: That's not efficient!

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit: Now I find fstream more powerful than ofstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (tested with the text file you've provided)

```
fstream file("file.txt", ios::in|ios::out);
string data;
file>>data;
data="olleh";
file.seekp(0);
file<<data;
file.close();
```

It depends on what you want to do exactely. Based on your example, I assumed you want to replace a word at the begining of the file with another word with the same length.